# Why does npm install use a different package version than our forked one?

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install, package.json

Since a few days, our aws elastic beanstalk fails to deploy our code through npm Install.
We are using our own fork from `parse-server` repo, and it always worked fine.

Unfortunately it now fails without obvious reason. When looking at the instance logs it clearly shows it tries to use the original `parse-server` repo (on a very old branch) instead of our very own fork, but I can't figure why.

Our `package.json` file indicates:

```
"parse-server": "git+https://github.com/hulab/parse-server.git#patched/5.3.0-hulab-2"
```

and our `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file reflects it with a

```
"parse-server": {
      "version": "git+https://github.com/hulab/parse-server.git#54bfd65181f19d4296f0ebea79cf3a4ab542f2fc",
      "from": "git+https://github.com/hulab/parse-server.git#patched/5.3.0-hulab-2",
...
}
```

Whereas the EC2 instance logs indicate failures when installing:

```
parse-server@github:parse-community/parse-server#892c6f94d50b6dced8a5e1948e058dc7b095c914
```

I can't figure out why this branch is used while not being referred to in any of our files!

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely another dependency that points to that specific version of Parse Server.

For example, the Parse JS SDK has a `devDependency` for integration tests:

```
"parse-server": "github:parse-community/parse-server#alpha"
```

Since you are using a customized version of Parse Server, check the Parse JS SDK (which is a component of Parse Server), and any other Parse dependency that you added, whether they have a parse-server dependency and to where it points. In `package.json` you may only see the branch name but in `package-lock.json` of that dependency you may see the actual commit hash you are referring to.

Comment: I was not aware that Parse JS SDK has a devDependency to parse-server as well, and I guess there's a conflict between the parse-server package we have in our package.json (and package-lock.json) and the one used by the Parse JS SDK itself used by the parse-server package.
Thanks again!